# Can only use 1/4 functions from C++ DLL in C# application

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, dllimport

Having a bit of trouble converting a C++ DLL for use in C#.

It is working.. The first C++ function in the DLL which is just: `int subtractInts(int x, int y)` and its typical body works no problem. All of the other functions are as simple and have been tested. However, I have been following a tutorial and doing some funky stuff to use that code in C# as a C++ DLL (for portability).

My steps are:

•   Create a C++ class, test it and save it – only using the ‘class.cpp’ and ‘class.h’ files
•   Create a Win32 library project in Visual Studio 2010, choose DLL on start up and for each function I want to expose to C#.. the below code

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int addInts(int x, int y)
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int multiplyInts(int x, int y)
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int subtractInts(int x, int y)
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) string returnTestString()
```

Pretty key point, that is the order I externed them in my DLL.

Then as a test because I did have this problem before.. I referenced them in a different way in my C# project

```
   [DllImport("C:\\cppdll\\test1\\testDLL1_medium.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    public static extern int subtractInts(int x, int y);
    public static extern int multiplyints(int x, int y);
    public static extern int addints(int x, int y);
    public static extern string returnteststring();
```

The ONLY function that work when called from C# is subtractInts, which is obviously the function referenced first. All others cause errors (see below) on compilation.

If I don't comment out that above code and go to externally reference all of those functions. I get the following error at multipyInts(int x, int y).

`Could not load type 'test1DLL_highest.Form1' from assembly 'test1DLL_highest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'multiplyints' has no implementation (no RVA).`

I would imagine that sorting that would sort everything.

Cheers.

Comment: attribute them all with DLLI<PORT attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `DllImportAttribute` to all four methods, remove the paths, and fix your casing:

```
[DllImport("testDLL1_medium.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int subtractInts(int x, int y);
[DllImport("testDLL1_medium.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int multiplyInts(int x, int y);
[DllImport("testDLL1_medium.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int addInts(int x, int y);
[DllImport("testDLL1_medium.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern string returnTestString();
```

Also make sure that the native DLL is in the same location as your managed assembly (or discoverable via normal DLL discovery methods).

Comment: Ok that taken care of the initial error but now when I try to call one of those functions e.g. `label2.Text = multiplyInts(4, 6).ToString();` I get this error.. `"Error 1 The name 'multiplyInts' does not exist in the current context \\selafap01\homedrives\mgibson\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1DLL_highest\test1DLL_highest\Form1.cs 32 27 test1DLL_highest` (The directory it is complied at obviously, but does the DLL not take care of all that?

Comment: @mgibson You should make sure the unmanaged DLL is in the executable folder (of the C# project), and not specify a "full path".

Comment: Also make sure your casing matches the DLL function names.  You have them different on all except `subtractInts`